# Convert String to Double with Known Format

Tags: c#

I need to convert a string back to a double, but the string is not always the same format. In one case it is "N0", in another "#,##", and yet another is currency "C0". The good thing is, I know what format the string is in as earlier in the process it was converted from double to string.

How can I convert back to a double. The numeric only values double.parse or Convert.ToDouble with ease, but the currency values do not.

```
string format = "{0:C0}";
double dollar = 1,234.00;
string dollarString = String.Format(format, doubleValue); // == "$1,234"
double newDollar = Convert.ToDouble(dollarString); // Fails
```

This last line is where the issue is. I'm assuming I need to use IFormatProvider or Culture or something, but I'm not exactly sure.

I cannot specifically reference the format is a Currency as the "format" isn't always a currency.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As I was typing this I came up with the following. Further feedback on whether this is a good way of doing it or if I might run into issues later.

```
double newDollar;
double.TryParse(dollarString, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat, out newDollar);
```

Comment: You could also pass in `TryParseExact` and pass in the formatting string you know it will match. (you can also pass in a array of strings if it could be one of several choices)

Comment: Note: CurrentCulture can end up parsing it the wrong way, if the computer language settings are different.
E.g. in Switzerland the delimiter for currencies is a dot (.) whereas in Germany its a comma (,).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain There is no such function like TryParseExact available in .NET.

Comment: @FabianBigler ill be damned, There isn't!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` make sure to you **set the CurrentCulture of your thread**.

Else it can end up in **parsing it the wrong way** (depending on the language settings on your computer).

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```

Then you can safely use this:

```
double.TryParse(dollarString, NumberStyles.Any, 
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat, out newDollar);
```

---

Alternatively, you can create a function like this (To get the right format without setting the culture).

**side note:** In Switzerland, this could cause troubles because the euros can still be parsed.
So 5,05 (€) would successfully be parsed to 505 (CHF). Trust me, you don't want this to happen.

```
public static double GetDouble(string value, double defaultValue)
{
    double numberToConvert;

    if (!double.TryParse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, 
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out numberToConvert) &&
        !double.TryParse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out numberToConvert) &&
        !double.TryParse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out numberToConvert))
    {
        numberToConvert= defaultValue;
    }

    return numberToConvert;
}
```